# Группировка полей по переданным параметрам

Tags: sql-server, sql

Добрый день.

Делаю к SQL Server функцию, возвращающую таблицу. В функцию, помимо остальных параметров, передаю **поле**, по которому нужно отсортировать и **направление сортировки**:

```
/* к примеру
@sidx = 'name';
@sord  = 'ASC';
*/
... тело запроса ...
ORDER BY @sidx @sord
```

Получаю "Incorrect syntax near '@sord'". В чём, собственно, ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте между `@sidx` и `@sord` поставить запятую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная в `ORDER BY` может входить только как часть выражения. Сработает, например, такая конструкция.

```
... тело запроса ... 
ORDER BY '['+@sidx+'] '+@sord
```

Comment: прошу прощения, не обратил внимания, что вторая переменная задает направление
ORDER BY '['+@sidx+'] '+@sord

Comment: после второй скобки пробел - правлю в ответе

Comment: в вашем случае после всех вычислений останется

       ... ORDER BY '[name] ASC'
Попробуйте ради интереса добавить такую сортировку к любому SELECT-у

Comment: все свои ответы я предварительно проверяю практически. и этот тоже проверил

Comment: вы меня не поняли. если вы допишите `ORDER BY '[name] ASC'` к абсолютно любому селекту, он отработает. Даже если в той таблице нет колонки `name`. Потому что он будет проводить именно то, что вы просите: сортировать по значению строки `'[name] ASC'`, которую будет приставлять к каждой строчке набора данных.

Comment: Ну, синтакической ошибки же удалось избежать.

Comment: А ну если дело только в ошибке было. ) Я то думал требовалось сделать параметризованную сортировку

Comment: Да, теперь заметил. Устранение грамматической ошибки - это не то что нужно, нужно чтобы работало правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Вы, кажется, плохо представляете себе грамматику SQL. `ASC` - это синтаксическая конструкция языка, `'ASC'` это просто строка. Далее должно следовать название столбца, например `name` . Вы же подставляете строку `'name'`. Чувствуете разницу?

Выхода два, и оба сводятся к генерации запроса:

1. Вы можете сгенерировать запрос со всеми подстановками в коде программы.
2. Вы можете сгенерировать запрос со всеми подстановками в TSQL и продолжать передавать параметры, как вы это делаете сейчас. Пример:

   ```
   declare @query varchar(255)

   set @query = 'select * from mytable order by ' + @sidx + ' ' + @sord
   execute(@query)
   ```

Comment: т.е сначала название столбца, а потом `ASC`, разумеется.

Comment: Вы плохо представляете себе возможности конкретно MS SQL Server. Выполните такой простой скрипт:

    create table #t (name varchar(20))
    insert into #t values ('Иванов')
    insert into #t values ('Петров')
    
    declare @sidx varchar(20), @sord varchar(20)
    
    set @sidx='name'
    set @sord='asc'
    
    select * from #t order by '['+@sidx+'] '+@sord
    
    drop table #t

Comment: Вы плохо себе представляете возможности SQL. Выполните такой простой скрипт:

        create table #t (name varchar(20)) insert into #t values ('Иванов') insert into #t values ('Петров')
        declare @sidx varchar(20), @sord varchar(20)
        set @sidx='name' set @sord='desc'
        select * from #t order by '['+@sidx+'] '+@sord
        drop table #t
;)

Comment: Слишком сложно?

Comment: так вы его выполнили или нет? Именной мой вариант. в нем, если присмотреться, я поставил направление DESC

Comment: Понял. Пардон. Подумаю еще.

Answer (score 1):

Задача, о которой Вы пишите, решается так: [Dynamic Order By](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-order-by)

Comment: Хм, интересно, сейчас нет возможности попробовать, но обязательно попробую.
А вариант с DESC/ASC так же получится: ...ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBY =...END CASE WHEN @sord = +' '+ASC THEN ' ASC' WHEN @sord = 'DESC' THEN +' '+DESC END...? Или как правильно будет?

Comment: Нет, так не получится. Вы можете, если сортировка по возрастанию, выполнить один запрос, если по убыванию - другой.

Comment: В смысле два одинаковых запроса, но в конце первого будет ASC а второго DESC? Можете пример привести?

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=5942

Comment: @Modus, кстати идея неплохая, но не очень удобна для таблиц с большим количеством столбцов (30 например) и совсем не удобна, если мы хотим сортировку по нескольким столбцам.

Comment: @Afipsky, так не получится. Проведу аналогию. Представьте, что вы пишете программу на обычно языке программирования (С, например). В вашем случае вы пытаетесь сделать что-то вроде:

       if (sord==true) { +; } else { -; }

т.е. используете в качестве вычисляемого выражения языковую конструкцию, которая сама по себе ничего не вычисляет и не возвращает значение (`ASC` только задает направление сортировки и ставится в строго определенном месте запроса).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Comment: Если у Вас несколько столбцов для сортировки, вообще не стоит делать сортировку внутри функции. Более правильным решением было бы создание представления, а список полей сортировки отрабатывался бы на уровне клиента, делающего запрос к этому представлению.